# Problem with luacode in sty file

Tags: luatex

I'm trying to include a gcd function using lua in a sty file.
Here is the code of euclide.sty :

```
\RequirePackage{ifluatex,luacode,luatextra}
\ifluatex
    \begin{luacode}
        function euclide(a,b)
            if a < b then a,b = b,a end
            r = a-math.floor(a/b)*b
            if r == 0 then tex.print(b) else euclide(b,r) end
        end
    \end{luacode}
    \newcommand{\euclide}[2]{\luaexec{euclide(#1,#2)}}
\fi
```

Here is the texfile code :

```
\documentclass[10pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{euclide}

\begin{document}
\euclide{435}{630}
\end{document}
```

The lualatex compilation give me errors :

```
Runaway argument?
! File ended while scanning use of \luacode@grab@lines.
<inserted text>
\par
l.4 

I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.


! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
```

Can somebody tell me what's wrong in my code ? (this code works fine in the main tex file, but not in sty file)
Thanks, MB.

Comment: This is 'works for me': could you perhaps add `\listfile` so we can see your file versions?

Comment: Just because I had tab character before \end{luacode}. Thanks all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can reproduce the problem, if the white space before `\end{luacode}` is a tabulator character. Environment `luacode` is a special environment, because it changes category codes to read its contents in a more verbatim way. Therefore the end detection is not done by the usual macro expansion, but by searching for the string `\end{luacode}` at the start of a new line (spaces are ignored with catcode 10 here).

Fix: Replace tabulators by spaces (depending on the editor, there might be an option for this.)

BTW: It is a little inconsistent: First packages are loaded that require LuaTeX (`luacode` and `luaextra`), then the code is wrapped in `\ifluatex`. If the package works with and without LuaTeX:

```
\RequirePackage{ifluatex}
\ifluatex
  \RequirePackage{luacode,luaextra}
  \begin{luacode}
  ...
  \end{luacode}
  ...
\else
  ...
\fi
```

Or test for LuaTeX and throw an error, if LuaTeX is required:

```
\RequirePackage{ifluatex}
\ifluatex
\else
  \PackageError{euclide}{LuaTeX is required}\@ehd
  \newcommand*{\euclide}[2]{%
    % dummy definition
  }%
  \expandafter\endinput % abort early
\fi

\RequirePackage{luacode,luaextra}
\begin{luacode}
...
\end{luacode}
```